# difference between select * and select table name

Tags: sql

This is the basic question about sql statements.

What is the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM "Users"
```

and

```
SELECT "Users".* FROM "Users"
```

Comment: Have you tried doing independent research before posting here? This seems like the kind of question you could find a reasonable answer to with a quick Google search.

Comment: Try viewing the execution plans to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 9):

[TableName].[column] is usually used to pinpoint the table you wish to use when two tables a present in a join or a complex statement and you want to define which column to use out of the two with the same name.

It's most common use is in a join though, for a basic statement such as the one above there is no difference and the output will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

In your case there is no difference. It emerges, when you are selecting from multiple tables. * takes data from all the tables, TABLE_NAME.* - all the data from *this* table. Suppose, we have a database with 2 tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM report;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2013-05-01 |
|  2 | 2013-06-02 |
+----+------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM sites_to_report;
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+
| site_id | report_id | last_run            | rows |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+
|       1 |         1 | 2013-05-01 16:20:21 |    1 |
|       1 |         2 | 2013-05-03 16:20:21 |    1 |
|       2 |         2 | 2013-05-03 14:21:47 |    1 |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+

mysql> SELECT
    ->  *
    -> FROM
    ->  report
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->  sites_to_report
    -> ON
    ->  sites_to_report.report_id=report.id;
+----+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+
| id | date       | site_id | report_id | last_run            | rows |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 2013-05-01 |       1 |         1 | 2013-05-01 16:20:21 |    1 |
|  2 | 2013-06-02 |       1 |         2 | 2013-05-03 16:20:21 |    1 |
|  2 | 2013-06-02 |       2 |         2 | 2013-05-03 14:21:47 |    1 |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------+

mysql> SELECT
    ->  report.*
    -> FROM
    ->  report
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->  sites_to_report
    -> ON
    ->  sites_to_report.report_id=report.id;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2013-05-01 |
|  2 | 2013-06-02 |
|  2 | 2013-06-02 |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of example given by you, there is no difference between them when it comes to semantics.When it comes to performance it might be too little... just parsing two different length strings....

But, it is only true for the example given by you. Where as in queries where multiple tables are involved `tableName.*` disambiguate the table from which table we want to select all columns.

Example:
  If you have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. Let's suppose that they have column with same names that is `Name`. If you want to specify from which table you want to select `Name` column. `Table-name` qualifier helps.

```
`select TableA.Name, TableB.Name where TableA.age=TableB.age`
```

That's all I can say.

Comment: this is not true in general, but only in the example stated above. as soon as there is more than one table involved there is a sematic difference.

Comment: @cproinger My answer is for the instance provided by him...the question is too short so is my answer...but that's what I intended he wanted to know whether there is any difference between using `*` and `table.*` not more than that I thought....

Comment: i don't know why odeds answer got an upvote, maybe for the humoristic touch in it. thanks for editing yours, this is much more helpful now, i changed my downvote into an upvote

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you provided, the only difference is in syntax. What both of the queries share is that they are really bad. `Select *` is evil no matter how you write it and can get you into all kinds of trouble. Get into the habit of listing the columns you want to have included in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

The particular examples specified would return the same result and have the same performance. There would be no difference in that respect, therefore.

However, in some SQL products, difference in interpreting `*` and `alias.*` has effect, in particular, on what else you can add to the query. More specifically, in Oracle, you can mix an `alias.*` with other expressions being returned as columns, i.e. this

```
SELECT "Users".*, SomeColumn * 2 AS DoubleValue FROM "Users"
```

would [work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1800/1). At the same time, `*` must stand on its own, meaning that the following

```
SELECT *, SomeColumn * 2 AS DoubleValue FROM "Users"
```

would be [illegal](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1800/2).