# mysql - use of regular expression in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a mysql query that would exclude rows starting by digits using regexp.
For instance here I have 1 column "indicators" with the following values:

```
5-Year Treasury Gilt Auction
52-Week Bill Auction
6-Month Bill Auction
ADP Nonfarm Employment Change
All Car Sales
```

I would like to create a query such as :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE indicators = [does not start with a digit...];
```

What is the right way to express such query in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.indicators regexp '^[^0-9].*$'
```

Or, you don't need regular expressions at all:

```
where left(t.indicators, 1) not between '0' and '9'
```

Comment: sorry i am quite noob: why `t.*` ? why not just `*`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  nice one +1 from me

Comment: @jimbasquiat both are same you can use * to select all columns. but if you join multiple tables then better to use tableName.tablecolumnName to avoid ambiguous column error.

Comment: get more idea here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884705/difference-between-select-and-select-table-name